# python input() EOF error and return value of type int?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have 2 questions on these 2 short codes.

1.

```
name = input('what: ')
print(name)
```

output

```
what: 641u
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vuthynun/PycharmProjects/untitled1/h/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input('what: ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    641u
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why does it give me this error?

2.

```
name = input('what: ')

print(type(name))
```

output:

```
what: 23
<type 'int'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is name type int? I thought all input are converted to string.

Please please please help me understand this. It's killing me.

Comment: Change `input()` to `raw_input()`. It looks like you're in python 2 which calls `eval` on whatever you give to `input`

Comment: Following the [official python2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input): "Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users."

Answer (score 3):

Use `raw_input` instead of `input` in python 2.
That's how you get strings. Otherwise python will evaluate what you give it, which is giving you your unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

This is the behavior in `Python 2.7`. Whatever you accept via `input` will be converted to type `int` and whatever you accept via `raw_input`, will be converted to type `str`.

For behavior in `Python 3`, check this: [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: This seems misleading - `input` does not convert anything, it evaluates whatever you give it. Try `2 + 3` for example.

Comment: I think you still misunderstand - try typing `"test"` into an `input` call. You'll notice that it comes out as a string, not an integer.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7. That is how it works there. May be I can specify that.