# Why does we see EOF error in python programming?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code by taking input from user in list through for loop, but there is a problem or unexpected behavior of python.
Here is my code image with error.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBsCU.png)

Please guide me or give any suggestions Thanks.

```
#calculator
elements = int(input("enter no of elements: "))
num1 = []
for i in range(elements):
    num2 = int(input("Enter numbers: "))
    num1.append(num2)
```

Comment: Please include your code as text, and not as an image. Also, the image you provided doesn't even show the full traceback, but I'm guessing you are getting an error because you didn't enter a number, so your call to `int` raised an error since it didn't know how to convert it. Also, you don't need to increment `i` at the bottom of the loop if you do `for i in range .... `. `i` is automatically incremented once it jumps back to the top.

Comment: Try to use `input(...).strip()` to get rid of the new line character from the input. Also, you could use the exception handler `try ... catch` to account for the wrong input type.

Comment: EOF on input only occurs on python 2. Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292743/python-input-eof-error-and-return-value-of-type-int

Comment: The code works fine on python 3 (tested on 3.6.5)

Answer (score 0):

As I tested your code on both python3 and as well as python2.7 there is nothing wrong with the code both codes are working fine getting input from first input() then moves towards next one. There is no such error.

But as you said there is an error and you also share your image with an error in line number 5 try to use ***raw_input*** instead of ***input*** in python 2.

Comment: Thanx brother i am looking forward to this.